# Venn diagram plot?

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I have some data as below, I would like to have Venn digram for them.Would you please let me know if there is any  solution.

```
dim(a)
1200

dim(b)
420

dim(c)
580

dim(d)
650
```

### Overlaps between data:

```
a_b = 200
a_c=100
c_b=20
a_d= 11
b_d= 61
c_d= 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways of building ViennDiagram. One is by  using VennDiagram package:

```
library(VennDiagram)
grid.newpage()
venn.plot <- draw.quad.venn(
  area1 = 1200,
  area2 = 420,
  area3 = 580,
  area4 = 650,
  n12 = 200,
  n13 = 100,
  n14 = 11,
  n23 = 20,
  n24 = 61,
  n34 = 0,
  n123 = 0,
  n124 = 0,
  n134 = 0,
  n234 = 0,
  n1234 = 0,
  category = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
  fill = c("orange", "red", "green", "blue"),
  lty = "dashed",
  cex = 2,
  cat.cex = 2,
  cat.col = c("orange", "red", "green", "blue")
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools to do just that. I developed one of them, called nVennR. With the data you have provided,

```
library(nVennR)
cVenn <- createVennObj(4, c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
cVenn <- setVennRegion(cVenn, c("a", "b"), 200)
cVenn <- setVennRegion(cVenn, c("a", "c"), 100)
cVenn <- setVennRegion(cVenn, c("c", "b"), 20)
cVenn <- setVennRegion(cVenn, c("a", "d"), 11)
cVenn <- setVennRegion(cVenn, c("b", "d"), 61)
cFig <- plotVenn(nVennObj = cVenn)
```

[image: Euler diagram]

However, you can do the same in one line directly from the lists a, b, c and d:

```
plotVenn(list(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d))
```